# make an option from select tag stays the same after reload or change the page, PHP

Tags: php

So im having problems on figuring out how to make option tag so when is pressed it will make the action on all the pages
This is what i have done:

```
index1.php
 include 'select.php'
<title>Ultra 2014 <?php if (isset($title)) {echo $title;} else{echo "Miami";}?> Area</title>

index2.php
 include 'select.php'
<title>Ultra 2014 <?php if (isset($title)) {echo $title;} else{echo "Miami";}?> Area</title>

select.php

<div id="regContainer">
    <form id="regionSelect" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" onchange="this.form.submit();" >
        <select id="selectedRegion" name="selectedRegion" size="1" autocomplete="off"> 
            <option  value="miami">miami</option>
            <option  value="new york">ny</option>
        </select>  
        <input type="submit" value="Enter Region" />
    </form>  
</div> 


process.php
<?php if(!isset($_SESSION)){ session_start();}


    if(isset($_POST['selectedRegion'])){

    $region = $_POST['selectedRegion'];

    if($region == "miami"){
    echo "miami selected";

    $title = "miami";

    }

    if($region == "new york"){
    echo "new york selected";

    $title = "new york";

     }


    }
?>
```

when I press the first option, it changes the title normally on the index1.php, but when i go to the index2.php... it does not change the title of that page, I have to press the first option button again to make the change.
Is there anyway to just press the first option from the selection and then change the title of all the pages without having to press the button again?

Any suggestion will help. Thanks

Comment: You have to go over each option in the select and if the value from the previous form is equal to that option then add `selected="selected"` to select that option.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, how can I set the cookie?

Answer (score 1):

Using the code you currently have you could do the following

```
<form id="regionSelect" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" onchange="this.form.submit();" >
        <select id="selectedRegion" name="selectedRegion" size="1" autocomplete="off"> 
            <option <?php if($_REQUEST['selectedRegion'] == 'miami') echo "selected"; ?>  value="miami">miami</option>
            <option <?php if($_REQUEST['selectedRegion'] == 'newyork') echo "selected"; ?>  value="newyork">ny</option>
        </select>  
        <input type="submit" value="Enter Region" />
    </form>
```

This will ensure the option is selected on page refresh. If you want something that also acts on page change then you will need to use a `cookie`

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['selectedRegion'])){
    setcookie("region", $_REQUEST['selectedRegion'], time()+3600);
}

<form id="regionSelect" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" onchange="this.form.submit();" >
            <select id="selectedRegion" name="selectedRegion" size="1" autocomplete="off"> 
                <option <?php if($_COOKIE["region"] == 'miami') echo "selected"; ?>  value="miami">miami</option>
                <option <?php if($_COOKIE["region"] == 'newyork') echo "selected"; ?>  value="newyork">ny</option>
            </select>  
            <input type="submit" value="Enter Region" />
        </form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Vector .. I figured the part on page refresh .. but how can I do it on page change?

Comment: My cookie example will do it on page change

Comment: Thanks Vector , the option now stays the same when changing the page... but is not doing the action that I did on the index1.php
So what i want is whenever i press the button it will make the button's action on all pages, changing the title of all the pages.
Any suggestions to do that? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)){ session_start();}
```

To just

```
session_start();
```

What you're saying currently is if you have a session set, don't load the session library to then use that session data.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion Ryan but if I do that i get this error:
Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()